# Retrofit response is not shown

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, retrofit

I want to fetch data from the server using Retrofit but it shows me **HTTP 500 server error** I know it is due to a null value in parameters but I don't where is the null value comes from. I try my best to find the null value but can't find it. If any other reason then please tell me.

**Here is my Fragment Code**

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    override fun inOnCreateView(mRootView: ViewGroup, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        val homeActivity = activity as HomeNavHostActivity
        homeActivity.toolbar_id?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        homeActivity.toolbar_search_icon_id.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        homeActivity.toolbar_add_icon_id.visibility = View.GONE
        homeActivity.home_view_layout?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        homeActivity.bottom_layout?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        homeActivity.toolbar_title_tv.text = "Home"

        homeActivity.toolbar_search_icon_id.setOnClickListener() {
            showSearchDialog(mRootView)

        }
        homeActivity.cancel_text.setOnClickListener() {
            homeActivity.search_layout.visibility = View.GONE
            homeActivity.toolbar_title_tv.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            homeActivity.search_view?.setQuery("", false)
            homeActivity.search_view?.clearFocus()
        }

        val dialogHelper by inject<MaterialDialogHelper>()
        setupProgressDialog(viewModel.showHideProgressDialog, dialogHelper)
        if (isNetworkAvailable(requireContext())) {
            var area:String = "20"
            var zipcode:String = "WC2N5DU"
            viewModel.getSkipFilterList(zipcode, area)
        } else {
            showAlertDialog(getString(R.string.no_internet))
        }
        attachViewModel()
    }
```

> **Here is my ViewModel Code**

```
 var filterSkipList: MutableLiveData<SkipListResponse> = MutableLiveData()
    fun getSkipFilterList(zipcode: String, area: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _showHideProgressDialog.value = true.wrapWithEvent()
            sharedWebServices.getFilterSkip(zipcode, area).run {
                onSuccess {
                    _showHideProgressDialog.value = false.wrapWithEvent()
                    if (it.code == VALID_STATUS_CODE) {
                        filterSkipList.value = it
                    }else {
                        showSnackbarMessage(it.message)
                    }
                }
                onFailure {
                    _showHideProgressDialog.value = false.wrapWithEvent()
                    it.message?.let { it1 -> showSnackbarMessage(it1) }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

> **Here is my data class**

```
 @Serializable
    data class SkipFilterList(
            val zipcode:String,
            val area:String
)
```

> **Here is my Post**

```
 @POST("search-skip")
    suspend fun skipListing(
            @Header("Authorization") token: String?,
            @Body body: SkipFilterList): SkipListResponse
```

**Here is My Repostry**

```
suspend fun getFilterSkip(
            zipcode: String,
            area: String
    ) = withContext(dispatcher) {
        val token = SharePrefrenceHelper.getInstance(app).getToken()
        val body = SkipFilterList(zipcode, area)
        safeApiCall {
            Result.success(apiServices.skipListing("Bearer" + token, body))
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the entire stacktrace?

Comment: No just the error. Try putting a lot statement in your `onFailure {` method. For example: `Log.e("Error loading data", it)` Now the error will show up in red in your logcat.

Comment: yes is can share

Comment: Logcat shows....2021-09-11 22:06:02.845 29293-29293/com.skipshare E/[Koin]: module 'org.koin.core.module.Module@ec48b90' already loaded!
2021-09-11 22:06:03.243 29293-29293/com.skipshare E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Comment: Try looking for a line that says something like "Error loading data HTTP 500 server error"

Comment: E/Error loading data: retrofit2.HttpException: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237022/discussion-between-faiz-and-kilian).

Answer (score 1):

By passing json object in the body this was solved.

```
val jsonObject = JsonObject()
jsonObject.addProperty("zipcode", zipcode)
jsonObject.addProperty("radius", area)
```